# Failed system checks when hosting application

Tags: python, django

When I try to host my web app, I get this:

```
(workout) sahands-mbp:workout sahandzarrinkoub$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x10ce3b950>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 125, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/Users/sahandzarrinkoub/Documents/Programming/Web/Django/workout/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 405, in check
    raise SystemCheckError(msg)
django.core.management.base.SystemCheckError: SystemCheckError: System check identified some issues:

ERRORS:
auth.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
auth.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.
workoutcal.User.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.groups'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.groups' or 'User.groups'.
workoutcal.User.user_permissions: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions' clashes with reverse accessor for 'User.user_permissions'.
    HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'User.user_permissions' or 'User.user_permissions'.

System check identified 4 issues (0 silenced).
```

I can't interpret this error message, because it doesn't look like a normal python error message. Before I got this error, I was experimenting with dropping sql tables from the application, and also with customising the default Django User model. Could this be a cause for the error? And how do I solve it?

Update:

I had this code in my **models.py**:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass
```

When I removed it, the error disappeared. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you follow these steps from the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project)?

> Don’t forget to point AUTH_USER_MODEL to it. Do this before creating
>   any migrations or running manage.py migrate for the first time.
>
> Also, register the model in the app’s admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```